# Is there any latency in SQS while creating it using AWS API and sending messages immediately after creating it

Tags: amazon-sqs

I want to create SQS using code whenever it is required to send messages and delete it after all messages are consumed.
I just wanted to know if there is some delay required between creating an SQS using Java code and then sending messages to it.
Thanks.
Virendra Agarwal

Comment: I've attempted to address your question in the answer, below.  Depending on your application, there might be better solutions.  Can you describe your use case in more detail?

Comment: I need to have a queue for each consumer who on-board platform. I can not have one queue for all consumers as messages will be entitled to different consumers. And SQS doesn't provide message identifier So queue must be created as soon as new consumer on board and messages will start flowing to it without delay.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to try it and make observations.  SQS is a dostributed system, so there is a possibility that a queue might not immediately be usable, though I did not find a direct documentation reference for this.

Note the following:

> If you delete a queue, you must wait at least 60 seconds before creating a queue with the same name.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_CreateQueue.html

This means your names will always need to be different, but it also implies something about the internals of SQS -- deleting a queue is not an instantaneous process.  The same *might* be true of creation, though that is not necessarily the case.

Also, there is no way to know with absolute certainty that a queue is truly empty.  A long poll that returns no messages is a strong indication that there are no messages remaining, as long as there are also no messages in flight (consumed but not deleted -- these will return to visibility if the consumer resets their visibility or improperly handles an exception and does not explicitly reset their visibility before the visibility timeout expires).

However, [`GetQueueAttributes`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_GetQueueAttributes.html) does not provide a fail-safe way of assuring a queue is truly empty, because many of the counter attributes are the *approximate* number of messages (visible, in-flight, etc.).  Again, this is related to the distributed architecture of SQS.  Certain rare, internal failures could potentially cause messages to be stranded internally, only to appear later.  The significance of this depends on the importance of the messages and the life cycle of the queue, and the risks of any such an issue seem -- to me -- increased when a queue does not have an indefinite lifetime (i.e. when the plan for a queue is to delete it when it is "empty").  This is not to imply that SQS is unreliable, only to make the point that any and all systems do eventually behave unexpectedly, however rare or unlikely.